# Overall application architecture with PRISM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-4

I am building a WPF application and plan on using the PRISM pattern library.  Almost all of my views will either display or modify a list.  Where should I place this object and how should I feed it to my views.  Should I just have a single module, create the object in the List in that object and then feed the object to the views upon creation of the views before injecting them into the various regions?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need only one module. The idea of modules is to seperate different parts of an application, e.g. order management and customer management.
2. Following the MVVM terminology the list is your model. Just name it ListModel. This ListModel should be wrapped with one view model. This could be named ListViewModel
3. All views have one view corresponding view model. These view models all have a reference to the ListViewModel. The ListViewModel is provided via a property to the views so the views can reference the ListViewModel using the binding path DataContext.ListViewModel. When your views are all bound to your view models it is irrelevant when your model is filled with data.

Comment: I agree I have mainly one model.  But I have about a dozen views that display/edit information about different portions of that model.  I can't see building one 'Master' ViewModel and then using it to display  different information/presentations of the data in different views.

Comment: The point is not to build one master view model but to build one view model per view that all use one view model that wraps the model. So when you have 5 views you therefore have 5 view models. These 5 view models all use the same sixth view model that contains the model.

Answer (score 1):

Prism is a very useful pattern library for what you are trying to do.
I advice you to take a look here http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/ you can find a lot of answers for the architecture of Prism and MVVM. You can define as much as module you want but if the views are similar like displaying and modifying a list, the best way is to identify what is changing from one view to another. Like binding or properties or label names and to generate those different views from Template T4 for example (or even if you want redifine them all one by one) It is gonna be one same module but with different binding for example.

If you want to share information between multiple viewmodels (regardless in which region/module they are) you could implement a shared service that stores a single List collection and inject that service in each viewmodel. Then, make each viewmodel access the data in the collection through the service, so when a CRUD operation is performed on the collection the changes will be reflected in all the viewmodels and then you can feed all your views.

If you are going to use that shared service and export it as a non shared export, the same instance of your ObjectRepository will be shared among all your viewmodels. When updating the List property in your service, you could make all your view models consume it.
If you will use unity, use singleton instance.

More details on shared service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec7

Comment: You did a good job of laying out a basic PRISM application.  But I can't see where you are passing a 'Master' list to the one module and you didn't define one in your module.  Your suggestion to check out http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/ is a good one though.